# Is "Alchemical breakthrough allows me to synth anything. Now what should I be making for sale?" on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, specific-question

I'm looking at [Alchemical breakthrough allows me to synth anything. Now what should I be making for sale?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/93240/29), and I can't quite make up my mind about it.

On the one hand, one can argue that it's about worldbuilding, because it is how someone might use an ability; in this case, the ability to synthesize anything. It's not limited to *a particular character* per se.

On the other hand, I don't really see any worldbuilding element to it. There is no clear *problem* to be solved. There are no clear criteria for how to judge answers on how well they answer the question; there is, however, a list of (relatively broad) criteria for the element to be created.

**Is the question on topic, or off topic? Why?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel like this is a case of [a question *trying* to be Good Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and ending up being Bad Subjective.

It's fine to have a question ask for the optimal solution to a problem - and we have many questions of this sort - but the question needs to have a way to evaluate an answer against another. If all answers are equally valid, then the question is too broad. The question makes an attempt to mitigate this by listing some limitations:

> - I can only make around 100 grams or a quarter of a pound of transmutations a day.
> - I can make any isotope, but only pure elements. No alloys.
> - I don't want anything too radioactive. Anything that can give me cancer over a day of exposure is too radioactive.
> - Toxicity is not an issue, only radiation. But see below:
> - I don't want to be flagged by the government, so nothing illegal / restricted.

However, it still asks for the "best" element to make - without defining what "best" is. Therefore, you have a range of answers that interpreted "best" in different ways:

- "Best" means high monetary value ([1](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/93252/627), [2](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/93296/627), [3](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/93250/627), etc.)
- "Best" means high scientific value ([1](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/93308/627), [2](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/93248/627))
- "Best" means interesting ([1](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/93247/627))

These answer types of pretty much orthogonal to one another, and I assume we'll get more. Until the objective of the question is cleared up, I would say the question should be closed as Too Broad.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably story generation, or at least really broad, but the [current second answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/93296/6751) is really good, and a really different take on the whole idea I'd never heard of before.

It does show that even normally bad questions can have valuable good answers that would be lost if the question never got asked.

I wonder if instead of closing questions like these, the best of them could be curated, and then used as "appears to be a duplicate of" for the next time someone asks a bad question.

Or at maybe just find a way to ask the same question and not have it be too broad, story based, etc, and use it as an example for when people do it wrong, as will keep happening.

Comment: The problem with your suggestion of curating these questions and using them as duplicate targets is that, unless someone else happens to ask *pretty much the same question*, there isn't any real basis for closing something else as a duplicate of it. And of course, if one form of a question is too broad, chances are pretty good that some other question that asks almost exactly the same thing is also too broad. It seems we haven't had much discussion on WB about canonical questions, but they are a thing on some other sites in the network, eg [sf], so *that* by itself can certainly be acceptable.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I'd be willing to bet that collectively we could come up with a version of that question that isn't too broad. If someone asks a similar question that is too broad then our good question will probably be able to fit inside of it. So we mark the broad one as a duplicate pointing to the good version, and then if they think that theirs is different and want it reopened they'll have to spell out why it's different, which means that they will be forced to narrow their question and get it to an acceptable status: "Oh, my question is different than that one because I want to know X"